# How to create checkbox in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, google-sheets, analysis

I was looking for a way to insert checkboxes in Excel cells as a Data Validation criteria. In the Excel settings for Data Validation, we only have **Any value**, **Whole Number**, **Decimal**, **List**, **Date**, **Time**, **Text Length** and **Custom**. In Google Sheets, we have **Checkbox** as one of them.

Comment: Well, *Microsoft* Excel is not *Google* Sheets.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on the top tabs/ribbons
2. Click Customize the Ribbon..
3. Check the Developer box on the right side
4. Click OK
5. Click the now visible Developer Tab
6. Click Insert Icon (Looks like a gray briefcase)
7. Click the Checkbox
8. Click the spot on the sheet where you want the checkbox